# Optionally match a literal string

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to match and capture the string `weather in foo bar`:

```
weather in ([a-z]+|[0-9]{5})\s?([a-zA-Z]+)?
```

Which will match and capture with `bar` being optional, and `foo` being able to be a city or a zip.

However, I would love to allow the user to write `weather in foo for bar`, since I have accidentally written this a few times myself. Is there any way to optionally capture a literal string like `for` without having to resort to `\s?f?o?r?\s?`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in a non-capturing group: `(?:\sfor\s)?`

Comment: So would the best way to match either a whitespace character OR the string ` for ` be `\s?(?:for\s)?`? Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @Gordon: You can also use an `or` with another non-capturing group:  `(?:\s|(?:\sfor\s))`.   Your way is shorter.  Note that you should remove the first `?`; the space is not optional.

Comment: Shouldn't the first space be optional, since I want everything after `foo` to be optional? I'll stick with the single capture-group. A bit easier for me to read.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the integrity of the 3 capture groups requires a little more work.
This might be a little advanced, but this is a good example of where assertions are helpfull.

`/weather\s+in\s+([[:alpha:]]+|\d{5})\s*((?<=\s)for(?=\s|$)|)\s*((?<=\s)[[:alpha:]]+|)/`

Test case in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samples = (
 'this is  the weather in 12345 forever',
 'this is  the weather in 32156 for ',
 'this is  the weather in 32156 for today',
 'this is  the weather in abcdefghijk for',
 'this is  the weather in abcdefghijk ',
 'this is  the weather in abcdefghijk end',
);

my $regex = qr/
  weather \s+ in \s+    # a literal string with some whitespace's
   (                    # Group 1
       [[:alpha:]]+        # City (alpha's), but without spaces
     | \d{5}               # OR, zip code (5 digits)
   )                    # end group 1
   \s*                  # optional whitespace's
   (                    # Group 2
       (?<=\s)             # must be a whitespace behind us
       for                 # literal 'for'
       (?=\s|$)            # in front of us must be a whitespace or string end 
     |                     # OR, match NOTHING
   )                    # end group 2
   \s*                  # optional whitespace's
   (                    # Group 3
       (?<=\s)             # must be a whitespace behind us
       [[:alpha:]]+        # 1 or more alpha's
     |                     # OR, match NOTHING
   )                    # end group 3
 /x;

for (@samples) {
    if (/$regex/x ) {
        print "'$1',  '$2',  '$3'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

`'12345',  '',  'forever'`
`'32156',  'for',  ''`
`'32156',  'for',  'today'`
`'abcdefghijk',  'for',  ''`
`'abcdefghijk',  '',  ''`
`'abcdefghijk',  '',  'end'`